# Use both Vuetify and Vue-i18n translations

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, vue-i18n

I am using Vuetify and want to add my own translations for buttons for example and also use the translations provided by Vuetify. I currently have my Vuetify config file setup like this:

```
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuetify from "vuetify"
import "vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css"
import "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
import VueI18n from "vue-i18n"
import messages from "./i18n"

import en from 'vuetify/es5/locale/en'
import nl from 'vuetify/es5/locale/nl'

Vue.use(Vuetify)
Vue.use(VueI18n)

const locale = navigator.language

const i18n = new VueI18n({
    locale: locale,
    messages: messages,
})

export default new Vuetify({
    theme: {
        themes: {
            light: {
                primary: "#8BC34A",
                secondary: "#627ACC"
            }
        }
    },
    icons: {
        iconfont: "fa",
    },
    lang: {
        locales: { en, nl },
        current: locale,
        t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params),
    },
});
```

My `locale` is set to `nl`, but also when I set it to `en` it gives me the following errors:

> Value of key '$vuetify.noDataText' is not a string! Cannot translate
>
> the value of keypath '$vuetify.noDataText'. Use the value of keypath
>   as default.

But when I add the Vuetify translation messages to my `i18n` file it works:

```
const messages = {
    en: {
        $vuetify: {
            noDataText: 'No data available',
        },
 }
```

But in an ideal situation I would like to separate the Vuetify translations, Dutch custom translations and English custom translations in different files. Could someone please help me find out how I can separate the translation logic?

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't customising vuetify's translations in vue-i18n then you don't need to integrate it. You can use vue-i18n the usual way for your own strings in your components and leave off `lang.t` in the vuetify options.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `messages` that you are passing to the `VueI18n` constructor  is just an object and as such you can compose it the way you want. You can compose it from multiple files, so you could have something like this in your `i18n` file:

```
import en from './locales/en;
import nl from './locales/nl';

export default {
  en,
  nl
}
```

Your `locales/en.js` might look something like this:

```
import $vuetify from './locales/en_vuetify';

export default {
  //Your english translations
  'foo1': 'foo1',
  // Your english vuetify translations
  $vuetify
}
```

And your `locales/en_vuetify.js` like this:

```
import enVuetify from 'vuetify/es5/locale/en'

export default {
  // These are the default vuetify translations
  ...enVuetify,
  // Here you write your custom vuetify translations that will override the default ones
  'custom1': 'whatever'
}
```

And in your `Vuetify` configuration object, you can leave the `lang` property just like this:

```
lang: {
  t: (key, ...params) => i18n.t(key, params),
},
```

This way it is `vue-i18n` the only one who takes care of the translations.